# Want columns value to be changed in output query

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I have a table `Test`:

```
 id   |  name    |  hide
  1   |  Paul    |  1
  2   |  John    |  
  3   |  Jessica |  2
```

Now I have three questions:

1. I want name column's value as '`PauAjit`' that mean if Name's last char is '`L`' the L should be replaced with '`Ajit`' in output
2. For '`hide`' column if value is `Null` then output should show `0` for that
3. If name column has value `John` then in output it should be replaced by `Ajit`

I have tried so far:

```
Select name case 
When name = 'paul' 
then replace(name, 'l', 'Ajit')  else name end from Test
```

Comment: Are you using both MS SQL Server and DB2 here? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: COALESCE(hide, 0), use CASE for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want name column's value as 'PauAjit' that mean if Name's last char is 'L' the L should be replaced with 'Ajit' in output.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(Name,1) = 'L' THEN STUFF(Name,LEN(Name),1,'Ajit') ELSE Name END
FROM
    MyTable
```

For 'hide' column if value is Null then output should show 0 for that.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(Hide,'0')
FROM
    MyTable
```

If name column has value John then in output it should be replaced by Ajit.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Name = 'John' THEN 'Ajit' ELSE Name END
FROM
    MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN name = 'John' 
     THEN 'Ajit' 
     WHEN RIGHT(name,1) = 'l' 
     THEN LEFT(name,3) + 'Ajit' 
     ELSE name 
     END AS name,
ISNULL(hide,'0')
FROM table
```

Comment: May I suggest COALESCE(hide, 0) instead?